# Class x.Savechanges(): No suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, error-handling

I want to check out `db.SaveChanges()` for error handling, and I put it into `EFentities` class' `SaveChanges()` method, but I have this error for `SaveChanges()`:

> No suitable method found to override

Here is my code:

```
public partial class EFentities
{
    EF db = new EF();

    public override int  SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting *No suitable methode found to override* error because you're neither defining `SaveChanges()` virtual method in the other side of partial class, nor defining any base class where the virtual method inherits from.

The `SaveChanges()` method available inside [`System.Data.Entity.DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) class with `virtual` signature like this:

```
public virtual int SaveChanges()
```

Hence, you should add `DbContext` as base class inherited by `EFEntities` to make `override` keyword work:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public partial class EFEntities : DbContext // add this base class
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // manual override goes here

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: public virtual int SaveChanges() for what is used?

Comment: That's the method name declared inside `DbContext` class (see the reference). You need to override that method in order to use your own custom `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: I ran the codes and didn't savechanges() save data and show errors i mean didn't go to cach()

Comment: Seems that currently you have different problem rather than error presented above. You can create another question for that and provide necessary details for further analysis.